# Canvas: caching imageData

Tags: qt, qml

In an earlier question ([propagateComposedEvents: mouse data not accurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34595544/propagatecomposedevents-mouse-data-not-accurate/34596144#34596144)) I have a routine (below) for checking if a mouse click point is on a transparent pixel in a `Canvas` component.

```
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(mouseX, mouseY, 1, 1)
```

Is there any performative reason to cache "imageData" since in my use case, it is not going to change? Or memory issue which would argue against caching. Or am I just staring at that line too long....

---

```
MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        drag.target: parent

        propagateComposedEvents: true

        onClicked: {
            var ctx = parent.getContext("2d")
            var imageData = ctx.getImageData(mouseX, mouseY, 1, 1)

            if (imageData.data[3] == 0 ){
                console.log("graphic alpha clicked:", mouseX, mouseY);
                 mouse.accepted = false;

            } else {
                 mouse.accepted = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image may not change, but looking at how you are getting only one pixel of it, and considering that the position of the click **will** change, caching is pointless unless you cache the entire image.

You should really profile, because there several factors at play here:

- does the imageData retrieval involve VRAM to RAM transfer - those are costly even for a single pixel
- how frequently does this happen
- how large is the entire image, is it viable to cache it entirely

Even if it not a performance hot spot, it is better to be efficient, doing unnecessary work just because you can get away with it is a bad habit, it consumers energy, CPU time and drains batteries. Doing a lot of this will eventually put you in a corner, as those stack up.